# Looping over input fields as array

Tags: bash, awk

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
$ cat foo.txt
1 2 3 4
foo bar baz
hello world
$ awk '{ for(i in $){ print $[i]; } }' foo.txt
1
2
3
4
foo
bar
baz
hello
world
```

I know you could do this:

```
$ awk '{ split($0,array," "); for(i in array){ print array[i]; } }' foo.txt
2
3
4
1
bar
baz
foo
world
hello
```

But then the result is not in order.

Comment: Yes, associative arrays are unordered collections.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Found out myself:

```
$ awk '{ for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { print $i; } }' foo.txt
```

Comment: Note you can delete the braces in `for` since you are executing just one command.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use sed:

```
sed 's/\ /\n/g' foo.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't work because I need to manipulate the seperated fields in awk. Or then I have to both involve sed and awk

Answer (score 1):

No need for `awk`, `sed` or `perl`.  You can easily do this directly in the shell:

```
for i in $(cat foo.txt); do echo "$i"; done
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're open to using Perl, either of these should do the trick:

```
perl -lane 'print $_ for @F' foo.txt
perl -lane 'print join "\n",@F' foo.txt
```

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around each line of the input file, do not automatically print the line
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the `@F` array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace.
- `-e` execute the perl code