# How to awk to find and replace string in 2,3,4 and 5th column if matching pattern exist

Tags: bash, awk

My text file consist of 5 columns. Based on the user input want to search only in 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th column and replace it.

for example

```
oldstring="Old_word" 
newstring="New_word"
```

So want to find all the exact match of oldstring and replace the same with newstring.
Column one should be untouched even if there is a match.

Browsed and found that awk will do but I am able to change in one particular column.

bash script

Comment: add couple of sample input line and expected output for that.. it would help for testing purposes as well as help in understanding the question better... here's an example of looping over input fields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997430/looping-over-input-fields-as-array please try something yourself and add to question

Comment: here's an example for changing specific field based on a condition - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23834095

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat testfile
a,b,c Old_word,d,e
f,gOld_wordOld_wordOld_words,h,i,j

$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v oldstring="Old_word" -v newstring="New_Word" '{
    for (i=2; i<=5; i++) { gsub(oldstring,newstring,$i) }
    print
}' testfile
```

```
a,b,c New_Word,d,e
f,gNew_WordNew_WordNew_Words,h,i,j
```

For more information about [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) read the [awk info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info)

Comment: it worked.
i added single quote for "awk -F',' -v OFS=',' " in my bashscript

Answer (score 1):

Another way, similar to Glenn Jackman's answer is :

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v old="Old_word" -v new="New_word" '{
      s=$1; $1=""; gsub(old,new,$0); $1=s
      print }' <file>
```